# How to restart log4j2 after call LogManager.shutdown()?

Tags: log4j2

I have a method to reconfig log4j2 like this:

```
LogManager.shutdown(); // SHUTDOWN log4j2
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my2ndLog4j2.xml");
    ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(in);
    Configurator.initialize(null, source);
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    context.reconfigure();
    context.start(); // NOT WORK, no log appear anymore...
```

So I can reconfig log4j2 between production log config and development config at runtime, but when I call  LogManager.shutdown(), it really SHUTDOWN forever, never get back, context.start() is not work, infact I do this in log4j1.x for long time, in log4j1.x, use:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(cfgPath);
```

then it get back, but how log4j2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change `log4j2` configuration file at runtime, then below code is sufficient to do so -

```
Configurator.initialize(null, "my2ndLog4j2.properties");
```

There is no need to shutdown `LogManager` and then starting it again.

Comment: This is not enough if you have multiple LoggerContext in your app.