# Restart log4j2 after shutdown

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

What's the way to properly start log4j2 after it's been shut down by `LogManager.shutdown()`?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046989/how-to-restart-log4j2-after-call-logmanager-shutdown) asking the same but it has no real solution as it was not necessary for what the OP intended. It is for me though.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there is no need to do this manually. Each LoggerContext registers a shutdown hook that takes care of releasing resources when the JVM exits (unless system property log4j.shutdownHookEnabled is set to false). Web applications should include the log4j-web module in their classpath which disables the shutdown hook but instead cleans up log4j resources when the web application is stopped.